# cycles VS evee : seems that some shadows are ignored?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I'm testing Eevee and it seems quite nice !
This is a scene with just a sun.
Here's how it looks in Eevee:

[image]

And now, with Cycles:

[image]

The mugs and the computers on the table almost don't have shadows with Eevee...
I know it is NOT Cycles and that shadows won't render as good as it.
But anyway, this look almost unrealistic.

What should I do to get better shadows ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe EEVEE is in development, so it would be fixed in future!:)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I know it is... But what I don't know is if this is a bug of Eevee or if my setup could be improved to get better shadows.

Comment: I don't work with Eevee, but you can see in cycles render that it has rendered as expected, maybe Eevee has a different node setup for showing shadows highlighted and noticeable like cycles! So wait till someone else could answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out for this particular problem !

Enable the "contact shadows" in the light panel !

[image]